# Unity: OnTriggerEnter2D not firing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I have a prefab for a red rectangle that has a BoxCollider2D set to trigger on it. I also have the player, controlled by the mouse, and it also has a BoxCollider2D (not set to trigger). When the player comes in contact, it should show a game over screen, but it does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image you provided in the comments, the `Simulated` property on your Rigidbody2D was turned off. Without this, the Rigidbody2D does not participate in the physics simulation, so the collider basically doesn't work.

So just enable the `Simulated` property.

Unity 2D physics uses Box2d. This `Simulated` property is referred to as activation in [Box2d documentation](https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_dynamics.html#autotoc_md64)

> You may wish a body to be created but not participate in collision or dynamics. This state is similar to sleeping except the body will not be woken by other bodies and the body's fixtures will not be placed in the broad-phase. This means the body will not participate in collisions, ray casts, etc.

Comment: I tried doing this. Both of the objects have a static Rigidbody2D with the Simulated property on. It still does not fire.

Comment: For the images you provided, where one rigidbody2d is dynamic, the only thing missing is that simulated is set to false. If you want them to be static now, that is a different thing. You should read about what the body types do. How are you moving a static rigidbody2d? it's not supposed to move.

Comment: Changed the player to be dynamic and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

To detect a collision in Unity, one of the two objects needs to have a Rigidbody2D attached to it. If the game is in 2D, the function to detect it is called "OnTriggerEnter2D", but in 3D, it's just "OnTriggerEnter".

If it still doesn't work after adding a Rigidbody2D to one of the objects, could you please show your scripts and maybe some screenshots of your Unity project?

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried a bunch of settings for the Rigidbody2D and none of them worked. Here's a link to some screenshots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p92pr1823ECKHBWo5uSTB8tsjzXKp0Fr?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello? You still there?

Comment: @Dolphin is one object passing through the other one very quickly?

Comment: @SpicyCatGames It was the Z coordinate, but now I'm having another issue (look at the edit)

Comment: @Dolphin that's not the issue. Make a different question for a different issue. I will only answer your original question. Also, 2d physics does not care about z position.